# can I rank results got from different WHERE clause?

Tags: postgresql

Say I want to select the posts that has certain tags or matches the keyword.

```
select t1.*
from (
select p.*, count(p.id) from plainto_tsquery('hElLo') AS q , post p 
left join post_tag pt on pt.post_id = p.id
left join tag t on t.id = pt.tag_id
WHERE (tsv @@ q) or t.id in (2,3)
group by p.id
) as t1 
order by count desc, ts_rank_cd(t1.tsv, plainto_tsquery('hElLo')) desc 
limit 5;
```

the above does select what I want. In `tsv`, I gave `title` A weight and `description` D weight. it now becomes pretty pointless when sorting by `count` because each entry has the same weight. Is it possible to do things like if this row is picked from `t.id in (2,3)`, they get to sorted to the first, then sort by `ts_rank_cd`, or give each match tag 'A' weight, title become B weight and description is D?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try CASE WHEN

```
select t1.*
from (
select p.*, count(p.id), 
(CASE WHEN t.id in (2,3) THEN 1 ELSE 2 END) as ranking 
from plainto_tsquery('hElLo') AS q , post p 
left join post_tag pt on pt.post_id = p.id
left join tag t on t.id = pt.tag_id
WHERE (tsv @@ q) or t.id in (2,3)
group by p.id
) as t1 
order by count desc, ranking asc, ts_rank_cd(t1.tsv, plainto_tsquery('hElLo')) desc 
limit 5;
```

Edited(**Correct Answer**):

```
select t1.*
from (
select p.*, count(p.id), 
COUNT(1) filter(where t.id in (2,3)) ranking
from plainto_tsquery('hElLo') AS q , post p 
left join post_tag pt on pt.post_id = p.id
left join tag t on t.id = pt.tag_id
WHERE (tsv @@ q) or t.id in (2,3)
group by p.id
) as t1 
order by count desc, ranking asc, ts_rank_cd(t1.tsv, plainto_tsquery('hElLo')) desc 
limit 5;
```

Comment: this seems to be closer to what I'm looking for but postgres is asking me to group by t.id too. this will create dup rows

Comment: actually there's a serious error in the goal that we gonna archive. Plz try edited answer.

Comment: you are my life saver! thank you so much. now I need to struggle on how to implement this to hibernate

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the count would be the same, but you can add more keys to the `order by`:

```
order by count desc,
         (t.id in (2, 3)) desc,
         ts_rank_cd(t1.tsv, plainto_tsquery('hElLo')) desc ;
```

The `desc` is because true > false, and you want the true values to be first.